# Response with Status 0 for URL : null

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 application which uses the same API as my previous ionic applications.

On logging in I am now getting the following error:

> Response with status: 0 for URL: null

I've looked around and everyone keeps referring to a CORS issue at server end, this can't be the case as my API worked previously and still does on existing applications.

Here's my login:

```
login(credentials) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.global.base() + 'login', JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: this.contentHeader })
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }
```

My config xml (trimmed for illustration):

```
<content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" spec="^0.1.11" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.4.0" />
```

My index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

My setup:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.14.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.14.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v7.7.1
    npm        : 4.1.2
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the WKWebView on ios. The WkWebView enfonces CORS and there is no way to disable it, so you need to whitelist the origin on your api like Access-`Control-Allow-Origin: *`. If you don't own the api you can use the native http plugin.

More info here https://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just checked my uri rest api, it ended with '/', I deleted it and everything is back in order