Intermittent web api call failure in Azure App Service
I have an Angular 14 front end running against a .Net 8 back end deployed to Azure App Service. I have recently started getting an intermittent error:
Response with status 0 for URL null
This has only started occurring since I moved to .Net 8.
Appreciate any help.
Barry

Might help with some examples of code calls but this might be something to look into ion the meantime? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917451/response-with-status-0-for-url-null

thanks I had found this also. The issue is actually happening on standard windows browsers.

I'd try a tool like Postman to see if you can actually get to the API outside the web-browser realm to see if the app is having the same issue when you try and get to it. Chances are it is a CORS issue. Do you have any CORS definitions in the .NET app being hosted? If its not a production level app you can see set it to allow all connections and see if that helps. If it does, then you'll definitely need to do some configuration work in the app to set the right CORS access levels.

The error "Response with status 0 for URL null" on .net 8 is often related to CORS.
Since it is happening on an intermittent basis it could be:

The failing requests are coming from a specific client that is not included in the CORS definition.


